# asp.net mvc 5 добавление записи в таблицу с навигационными полями

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Краткое описание: при добавлении записи в БД, модель помечается как не валидная, а вызов кода

```
return View(order);
```

Ошибки валидации для свойств (они не заполняются, заполняются поля с Id):
`public Product Product { get; set; }`
`public Employee Employee { get; set; }`
`public Customer Customer { get; set; }`

Код View

```
@using Bakery.Models
@model Bakery.Models.Order

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Добавить заказ";
}

@helper FIOEmployee(List<Employee> empCollection)
{ 
<select id="EmployeeId" name="EmployeeId">
    @foreach (var item in empCollection)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id">@string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", item.IdentificationNumber, item.Surname, item.Name, item.Patronymic)</option>
    }
</select>
    }

    <h2>Добавить заказ</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Order</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, ViewBag.Products as SelectList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, ViewBag.Customers as SelectList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @FIOEmployee(ViewBag.Employees as List<Employee>)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Count, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Count, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Count, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 }

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Назад к списку", "Index")
</div>
```

Код контроллера:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Bakery.Models;

namespace Bakery.Controllers
{
public class OrderController : Controller
{
    private BakeryContext db = new BakeryContext();

    // GET: Orders
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var orders = db.Orders.Include(p => p.Product).Include(p => p.Customer).Include(p => p.Employee);
        return View(await orders.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Orders/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        SelectList products = new SelectList(db.Products, "Id", "Name");
        var employees = db.Employees.ToList();
        SelectList customers = new SelectList(db.Customers, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.Products = products;
        ViewBag.Employees = employees;
        ViewBag.Customers = customers;
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Orders/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Product,ProductId,Employee,EmployeeId,Customer,CustomerId,Count,Price")] Order order)
    {
        SelectList products = new SelectList(db.Products, "Id", "Name");
        var employees = db.Employees.ToList();
        SelectList customers = new SelectList(db.Customers, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.Products = products;
        ViewBag.Employees = employees;
        ViewBag.Customers = customers;
        order.Customer = db.Customers.Find(order.CustomerId);
        order.Employee = db.Employees.Find(order.EmployeeId);
        order.Product = db.Products.Find(order.ProductId);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            order.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.Orders.Add(order);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(order);
    }

    // GET: Orders/Edit/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Order order = await db.Orders.FindAsync(id);
        if (order == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(order);
    }

    // POST: Orders/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Count,Price")] Order order)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(order);
    }

    // GET: Orders/Delete/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Order order = await db.Orders.FindAsync(id);
        if (order == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(order);
    }

    // POST: Orders/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
    {
        Order order = await db.Orders.FindAsync(id);
        db.Orders.Remove(order);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
}
```

Код модели

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Bakery.Models
{
public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {

    }

    public Order(Employee employee, Product product, Customer customer, Double count, Double price)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Employee = employee;
        Product = product;
        Customer = customer;
        Count = count;
        Price = price;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Код
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Сотрудник
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Сотрудник")]
    [Required]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    [System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Guid? EmployeeId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Изделие
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Изделие")]
    [Required]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    [System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Guid? ProductId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Заказчик
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Покупатель")]
    [Required]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    [System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Guid? CustomerId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Количество заказанных изделий
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Количество изделий (шт.)")]
    [Required]
    [Range(1, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Количество не может быть меньше 1")]
    public double Count { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Цена
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Цена (руб.)")]
    [Required]
    [Range(0.1, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Цена не может быть меньше 0.1")]
    public double Price { get; set; }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Get методе Create у вас есть вот такой наборчик:

```
ViewBag.Products = products;
ViewBag.Employees = employees;
ViewBag.Customers = customers;
```

А в методе Post его нет, надо помнить что с каждым новым запросом модель новая, поэтому сотрудники и продукты должны заново заполняться

Comment: Действительно, ошибка пропала, но данные не добавляются, т.к. `ModelState.IsValid` равен false

Comment: @Alexandr значит какие то поля неправильно заполнены или не заполнены вообще, надо через дебагер смотреть

Comment: в вопросе написано какие пустые

Comment: @Alexandr значит нужно переместить Required на ProductId, EmployeeId

Comment: спасибо, помогло